# Ungroupable line break using wl-pprint

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I'm writing a pretty-printer for a simple white-space sensitive language.

I like the Leijen pretty-printer library more than I like the Wadler library, but the Leijen library has one problem in my domain: any line break I insert may be overridden by the `group` construct, which may compress any line, which might change the semantics of the output.

I don't think I can implement an ungroupable line in the wl-pprint (although I'd love to be wrong).

Looking a bit at the wl-pprint-extras package, I don't think that even the exposed internal interface allows me to create a line which will not be squashed by `group`.

Do I just have to rely on the fact that I never use `group`, or do I have some better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you want to be able to group and you also need to be able to ensure some lines aren't uninserted, 
why don't we use the fact that the library designers encoded the semantics in the data type, 
instead of in code. This fabulous decision makes it eminently re-engineerable.

The `Doc` data type encodes a line break using the constructor `Line :: Bool -> Doc`. 
The Bool represents whether to omit a space when removing a line. (Lines indent when they're there.)
Let's replace the Bool:

```
data LineBehaviour = OmitSpace | AddSpace | Keep

data Doc = ...
    ...
    Line !LineBehaviour   -- not Bool any more
```

The beautiful thing about the semantics-as-data design is that if we replace 
this `Bool` data with `LineBehaviour` data, functions that didn't use it but 
passed it on unchanged don't need editing. Functions that look inside at what 
the Bool is break with the change - we'll rewrite exactly the parts of the code
that need changing to support the new semantics by changing the data type where 
the old semantics resided. The program won't compile until we've made all the 
changes we should, while we won't need to touch a line of code that doesn't 
depend on line break semantics. Hooray!

For example, `renderPretty` uses the `Line` constructor, but in the pattern `Line _`,
so we can leave that alone.

First, we need to replace `Line True` with `Line OmitSpace`, and `Line False` with `Line AddSpace`,

```
line = Line AddSpace

linebreak = Line OmitSpace
```

but perhaps we should add our own

```
hardline :: Doc
hardline = Line Keep
```

and we could perhaps do with a binary operator that uses it

```
infixr 5 <->
(<->) :: Doc -> Doc -> Doc
x <-> y = x <> hardline <> y
```

and the equvalent of the vertical seperator, which I can't think of a better name than very vertical separator:

```
vvsep,vvcat :: [Doc] -> Doc
vvsep = fold (<->)
vvcat = fold (<->)
```

The actual removing of lines happens in the `group` function. Everything can stay the same except:

```
flatten (Line break)    = if break then Empty else Text 1 " "
```

should be changed to

```
flatten (Line OmitSpace)    = Empty
flatten (Line AddSpace)     = Text 1 " "
flatten (Line Keep)         = Line Keep
```

That's it: I can't find anything else to change!

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you. When I need something like this for a bigger/more important project, I'll look here.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to avoid `group`, yes. The library's designed to facilitate wrapping or not wrapping based on the width of the output that you specify.

Dependent on the syntax of language you're implementing, you should also be cautious about `softline` and `softbreak` and the `</>` and `<//>` operators that use them. There's no reason I can see that you can't use `<$>` and `<$$>` instead.

`sep`, `fillSep`, `cat` and `fillCat` all use `group` directly or indirectly (and have the indeterminate semantics/width-dependent line breaks you want to avoid). However, given the your purpose, I don't think you need them:

Use `vsep` or `hsep` instead of `sep` or `fillSep`.
Use `hcat` or `vcat` instead of `cat` or `fillCat`.

You could use a line like

```
import Text.PrettyPrint.Leijen hiding (group,softline,softbreak,
                                      (</>),(<//>),
                                      sep,fillSep,cat,fillCat)
```

to make sure you don't call these functions.

I can't think of a way to ensure that functions you do use don't call group somewhere along the line, but I think those are the ones to avoid.

Comment: I guess if I cared enough, I could rewrite the library with a different underlying data structure which has an ungroupable line constructor. It shouldn't change the algorithm much, should it?

It just so happens that most of those combinators are okay for my language. The only invariant I need is that two statements are never grouped.

Comment: Easier than a rewrite is: Copy the course, comment out `group`, comment out the other functions I mentioned and compile. After every compiler error, comment out the function with the error. That way you get a `group`-free library of your own. Call it `Text.PrettyPrint.LeijenHardLine` and install it locally, or just save it in the same folder as your other code if your project is something smaller.

Comment: But I'm prone to over-engineering, and there are places where I want to be able to group, and other places where I want to ensure that there's no grouping happening. My actual solution is just to be careful.